# How do I convert a query string into a slash URL in php?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert a URL from

```
http://localhost/projectname/api/index.php?type=login
```

to

```
http://localhost/projectname/api/login
```

Comment: (Do you want to handle that in Apache configuration (tag) or in a PHP script (title, sort of)?)

Comment: In project .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

**Convert** is not a got term here.

The question with htaccess in your case is, what should happen with a request that is coming **from a Browser**. If you like that a request from the browser looks like `http://example.com/projectname/api/login` but internally it should do `http://example.com/projectname/api/index.php?type=login` than this is called **rewrite**.

The other option is that you want to have a **redirect**, that means if a browser is requesting e.g. `http://example.com/projectname/api/login` the server respond with the correct URL e.g. `http://example.com/projectname/api/index.php?type=login` and the browser now loading this page instant. If you test this in your Browser you will see that the URL will change.

So for a internal rewrite you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite from e.g. /projectname/api/login to /projectname/api/index.php?type=login
RewriteRule ^/?projectname/api/(.*)$ /projectname/api/index.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

for a redirect you do

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect from e.g. /projectname/api/login to /projectname/api/index.php?type=login
RewriteRule ^/?projectname/api/(.*)$ /projectname/api/index.php?type=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This will redirect or rewrite e.g `/projectname/api/login` to `/projectname/api/index.php?type=login` or `/projectname/api/logout` to `/projectname/api/index.php?type=logout`

Of core this is is also possible the **other way around** for rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite from e.g. /projectname/api/index.php?type=login to /projectname/api/login
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^/?projectname/api/index.php$ /projectname/api/%1 [L]
```

And also for redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect from e.g. /projectname/api/index.php?type=login to /projectname/api/login
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^/?projectname/api/index.php$ /projectname/api/%1 [R=301,L]
```

### But

If you have some HTML output and you want to change the output before it is served **to the browser**, .htaccess could not help you, you have to do it in your PHP application.