# Rewriting urls into one level links with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I want to achieve is this:

```
website/index.php?post=my-post-name
```

To become:

```
website/my-post-name
```

And I would like to get the post name using **$_GET['post']**.

My **.htaccess** rewrites the urls in a way I need, but I'm not able to retrieve the post name by using $_GET. It's empty.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/* index.php?post=$1
```

**What's the problem?**

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: [another pos dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583684/how-do-i-convert-a-query-string-into-a-slash-url-in-php), [another pos dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468946/rewrite-rule-in-htaccess-convert-query-string-into-slashes-php)

Comment: @anubhava That's what I wanted. Thank you, Sir.